# Обратный отсчет до времени unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть время в unix timestamp: **1588264807**

Как сделать обратный отсчет до этого времени на jquery или чистом JavaScript?

Хотелось быть чтобы было вида **часов:минут:секунд**, например: 00:01:25

Буду очень благодарен за помощь или любую полезную информацию!

Comment: Вычесть текущее время `Date.now()/1000`, ну а перевести секунды в минуты и часы это уже школьная математика

Comment: @andreymal, получается когда время вышло, оно продолжает опять запускать отсчёт почему-то. Можно ли как то сделать чтобы этого не происходило, а было написано 00:00:00?

Comment: Проверить что значение секунд счётчика не меньше нуля, очевидно

Answer (score 0):

```
function startTimer(time) {
    const elementClock = document.querySelector('.time');
    const milliseconds = 1000;
    let currentTime = time;

    const idInterval = setInterval(() => {
        const dateObj = new Date(currentTime);

        const hours = dateObj.getHours();
        const minutes = dateObj.getMinutes();
        const seconds = dateObj.getSeconds();

        elementClock.innerHTML = `${hours} : ${minutes} : ${seconds}`
        currentTime -= milliseconds;

        if(currentTime < 1000) {
            clearInterval(idInterval);
            elementClock.innerHTML = '00 : 00 : 00';
        }
    }, milliseconds);
}
```